# How can I get the zoom level, latitude/longitude values, and center of the Map when zooming in/out?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing an application based on the MapKit using the iPhone SDK. Now I just need a method to get the event when we drag, zoom in/out on the Map. The method is like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Now I need to get the following:

- Top left's and bottom right's latitude and longitude values.
- Center of the map.
- Zoom level.

Please give me suggessions to solve the above 3 use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following code I got the answer to get the values of center,topleft and bottom right latitude and longitude values of the map view. I need to get a solution for the answer question as well (i.e zoo level of the mapview). If you guys have any idea to get the zoom level please post me. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

       double centerLatitude= mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude;
       double centerLongitude= mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude;

       double topLeft Latitude= (mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude)+(mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta)/2;

       double topLeft Longitude= (mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude)-(mapView.region.span.longitudedeDelta)/2;


       double bottom Right Latitude= (mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude)-(mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta)/2;

       double bottom Right Longitude= (mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude)+(mapView.region.span.longitudedeDelta)/2;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
        MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = mapView.bounds.size.width / mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;
        NSLog(@"current zoom scale is %f",currentZoomScale);
}
```

To get the current zoomlevel you can use `getZoomLevel` method of `mapview`
like this:

```
NSLog(@"i am class regiondidchange   %f", [mapView getZoomLevel]);
```

how i can affect accordingly to circle radius in map.